# Dynamic placeholder configuration in liquibase generated dynamic checksums

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, hsqldb

I am using spring, liquibase with hsql database. I am creating a sequence for a table, let's say example table. The sequence will be created from the liquibase like the following

```
<changeSet id="xx" author="yy" dbms="hsql">
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
<not>
<sequenceExists sequenceName="example_id_sequence"/>
</not>
</preConditions>
<createSequence sequenceName="example_id_sequence" startValue="${hsql.exampleSequenceCount}" incrementBy="1"/>
</changeSet>
```

As you notice here, the startValue for the sequence is got from a external java code using changelog parameters of liquibase bean.

> The first startup works fine. After inserting some data into the
>   example table, when I restart the startValue now will be max Id+1
>   value of the table, it is returned like that for a requirement.

so the check sum changes and error is thrown. I tried including pre conditions, that also did not work. Is there any workaround for this like

> If there is a sequence present, don't check the checksum and don't
>   create a new sequence

Comment: Have you tried using `<validCheckSum>your-check-sum</validCheckSum>`?  It should make checkSum for this changeSet constant, so this changeSet will be executed only once.

Comment: Yes it worked fine after using <validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround try adding:

`<validCheckSum>your-check-sum</validCheckSum>`

or:

`<validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>`

It should make checkSum for this changeSet constant (or non-unportant in case of `ANY`), so this changeSet will be executed only once.